# REDUX: Trying to add an incrementer and decrementer but it wont work

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

action-types.js

```
export const INCREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT = "INCREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT"
export const DECREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT = "DECREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT"
```

reduxActions.js

```
    export function incrementWidgetCount(){
  return { type: INCREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT}
}

export function decrementWidgetCount(){
  return { type: DECREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT}
}
```

reduxReducer.js

```
    const initialState = {
    renderedEl: {
        heimdall: false,
        skadi: false,
        mercator: false
    },
    layoutInitialAppSelected: false,
    selectedAppToRender: "",
    numberOfWidgets:0
}

    function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {

        if (action.type === RENDER_LAYOUT_ELEMENT) {
            return { ...state, renderedEl: { ...state.renderedEl, ...action.payload } };
        } else if (action.type === TRIGGER_FIRST_WIDGET_SELECT_LAYOUT) {
            return { ...state, layoutInitialAppSelected: action.payload }
        } else if (action.type == SELECTED_APP_TO_RENDER) {
            return { ...state, selectedAppToRender: action.payload }
        } else if(action.type == INCREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT){
            return state.numberOfWidgets + 1;
        }else if(action.type == DECREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT){
            return state.numberOfWidgets - 1;
        }

        return state
    }
```

Thats how my redux code currently works. I wanted to create an incrementer and decremetner of the state.numberOfWidgets. So now in my app, im calling it like this:

```
import {  incrementWidgetCount, decrementWidgetCount } from "../redux/actions/reduxActions.js"

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {
    incrementWidgetCount: element => dispatch(incrementWidgetCount(element))
    decrementWidgetCount: element => dispatch(decrementWidgetCount(element))
}
```

}

And then in a function, in its end I simply do:

```
this.props.incrementWidgetCount();
```

And its then, when the app crashes, with a completly unrelated error, related to this.props.renderedEl.skadi being undefined, it crashes in another js file, where it works properly up until I call the increment or decrement function.

Whats going on?

EDIT: I did this, the app now wont crash, but it doesnt increment the number

```
else if(action.type == INCREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT){
    return { ...state, numberOfWidgets: { ...state.numberOfWidgets, ...state.numberOfWidgets +1}}
}
```

EDIT: This is how i read the store
I have this in the beggining, befor the class

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
        renderedEl: state.renderedEl,
        selectedAppToRender: state.selectedAppToRender,
        layoutInitialAppSelected: state.layoutInitialAppSelected,
        numberOfWidgets: state.numberOfWidgets }
}
```

And then in the end of this piece i read the store

```
 closeAddModal = (el) => {
    var elementName = el.target.getAttribute('name');

    var element = {
        "heimdall": "a",
        "skadi": "b",
        "mercator": "c"
    }

    var layouts = this.state.layouts;


    layouts.lg.push({ i: element[elementName], x: 6, y: 0, w: 6, h: 6.45 })
    layouts.md.push({ i: element[elementName], x: 5, y: 0, w: 5, h: 4.35 })
    layouts.sm.push({ i: element[elementName], x: 0, y: 5, w: 6, h: 4.55 })
    layouts.xs.push({ i: element[elementName], x: 0, y: 3.5, w: 4, h: 3.40 })
    layouts.xxs.push({ i: element[elementName], x: 0, y: 2.5, w: 2, h: 2.35 })

    this.setState({
        layouts: layouts
    }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.layouts)
        this.setState({
            addAppModal: false
        }, () => {
            var renderedEls = this.props.renderedEl;
            for (let key in renderedEls) {
                if (key == elementName) {
                    renderedEls[key] = true
                }
            }

            this.props.renderLayoutElement(renderedEls);
            this.props.triggerFirstWidgetSelectLayout(true);

            console.log("counter before increment")
            console.log(this.props.numberOfWidgets) //0
            this.props.incrementWidgetCount();
            console.log("counter after increment")
            console.log(this.props.numberOfWidgets) //0
        })

    }
    )

}
```

Comment: Given your initial state, you should try something like:   
`else if(action.type == INCREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT){
    return { ...state, numberOfWidgets: state.numberOfWidgets+1}
`

Comment: @Ay_mhwan it doesnt crash that way, but the increment doesnt work

Comment: Can you log ? like 
`else if(action.type == INCREMENT_WIDGET_COUNT){ const x = { ...state, numberOfWidgets: state.numberOfWidgets+1} print(x) return x}`

Comment: @Ay_mhwan in the log, I can actually see the counter incrementing in the log ```{renderedEl: {…}, layoutInitialAppSelected: true, selectedAppToRender: "", numberOfWidgets: 1}
layoutInitialAppSelected: true
numberOfWidgets: 1
renderedEl: {heimdall: true, skadi: false, mercator: true}
selectedAppToRender: ""
__proto__: Object```

Comment: So how do you listen to the change of the redux store ? 
I guess ` store.subscribe(() => console.log("updated", store.getState()))` should work
Are you using react ? in this case your component should looks like that: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react
Please share your react component (it should be wrap in the connect function)

Comment: @Ay_mhwan I updated the code. I dont use subscripe, since afaik I can read it using a mapstatetoprops, or at least thats how ive been doing it so far

Comment: Did you wrap your component with connect ?

Comment: @Ay_mhwan yes ````export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GridLayoutApps)```` After all im able to use and manipulate the different stores that I have. Thats the only one that I cant read

Comment: Wait after:
`this.props.incrementWidgetCount();
            console.log("counter after increment")
            console.log(this.props.numberOfWidgets) //0` you mean here you want to see 1 ?

Comment: yes @Ay_mhwan . And by the way ive just fixed it using a subscribe. But i thought that i could use the mapstatetoprops to do so

Comment: @Ay_mhwan you can check the answer that I have written. I wont accept my own answer yet, but it seems to work

Comment: It is normal that this.props.numberOfWidgets was still 0. because this is how redux + react works. because your state is immutable, it is at next render that you will have the correct value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212774/discussion-between-mouchin777-and-ay-mhwan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda fixed by importing the store in the .jsx file , and using

```
        console.log("counter before increment")
            console.log(this.props.numberOfWidgets) //0
            this.props.incrementWidgetCount();
            console.log("counter after increment")
            console.log(this.props.numberOfWidgets) //0
            console.log(store.getState().numberOfWidgets) //this returns 1
```

I dont know if theres a better way

EDIT: Found a better way. Using did update and then reading the state

```
if(this.state.numberOfWidgets != this.props.numberOfWidgets){
        // console.log("pre set state")
        // console.log(this.state.numberOfWidgets)
        this.setState({
            numberOfWidgets: this.props.numberOfWidgets
        }, () => {
              console.log("post set state number of widgets")
              console.log(this.state.numberOfWidgets)
        })
    }
```